# Cpanel issue but works on home PC

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cpanel

I have found a similar topic to my situation on this link - [POST net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in React nodemailer contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178858/post-neterr-connection-refused-in-react-nodemailer-contact-form)

This code is from https://w3collective.com/react-contact-form/

Which is what I am also using. The tutorial was well input for PC - but not on the live production server. Every time I try to change the localhost to https://server-ip-address:5000/contact it still gives me the ContactForm.js:16 POST https://localhost:5000/contact net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
let response = await fetch("https://localhost:5000/contact", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(details),
```

Comment: Perhaps the port on the server is not 5000? You'll need to check with your host what port they are using for nodemailer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have any good tutorials on how to find ports with WHM/Cpanel?

Comment: ```app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));```
This is a nodejs and there has to be a way that I can set that on cpanel